# Int behavior not expected

Tags: string, swift, integer, decimal

```
Label.text = "\(((labelPassedData.text!.toInt()! * 
labelPassedData2.text!.toInt()!) + (labelPassedData10.text!.toInt()! * 
labelPassedData11.text!.toInt()!))/1600)"
```

Dividing results in Int but no Float or Double is converted properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer is always a round number without decimals. If you need a number with decimals, you need something like a `Double`.

This extension will help you to get a double value from your String:

```
extension String{
    func toDouble() ->Double{
        return (self as NSString).doubleValue
    }
}
```

Use it like that:

```
labelPassedData.text.toDouble() //Your text as Double
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are performing purely integer arithmetic and the result is being assigned to a string value. There's no way that the compiler could figure out that you want to have a floating point value.
Best bet is to directly cast the string values to floats like this

```
(labelPassedData.text as NSString).floatValue
```

then divide by 1600.0

Comment: I get back "cast from String? to unrelated type 'NSString' always fails'